# How to avoid duplication in XSL transformations?

Tags: xml, xslt, code-duplication

In our application, XML documents of the following structure (much simplified) need to be processed:

```
<FooBar>
  <Foo ID="attr.1">value1</Foo>
  <Foo ID="attr.2">another value</Foo>
  <Bar ID="attr.3">
    <Foo>1</Foo>
    <Foo>2</Foo>
  </Bar>
</FooBar>
```

These documents are processed using 2 different transformations. Both transformations mainly target the `Foo` elements and some supporting information that is not displayed in the example above. The first transformation outputs csv where a `Foo` element is converted into it's own line. The other transformation just outputs the `Foo` elements as a comma separated list.

Example output of first transformation is:

```
attr.1-0;attr.1;value1
attr.2-0;attr.2;another value
attr.3-0;attr.3;1
attr.3-1;attr.3;2
```

Example output of the second transformation is:

```
attr.1-0,attr.2-0,attr.3-0,attr.3-1
```

When comparing both transformations they share about 75% of code. In fact the only difference is the named template that is actually used to output text.

The transformations look like the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- output some header information -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Foo" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Bar" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Bar">
  <!-- here is also some stuff -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Foo" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Foo" >
  <!-- output the text that is special to transformation 1 or 2 -->
</xsl:template>
```

How can I prevent that much code duplication in both transformations?

Comment: Are you already utilising XSLT templates for common code and calling these templates within each transformation?

Comment: @GarethWhittaker yes, and we already do use includes too, however, the problem is that from the template that matches the `Foo` element to the template that outputs the text, the distinction between either being in transformation 1 or 2 needs to be made..

Comment: SpaceTucker, There are powerful design patterns using which one can create truly reusable, elegant and powerful higher-order code. I have provided a complete simple example in my answer, and pointers to more details for the interested people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just to reorganize the whole code to some new files.

The point I was missing is that a stylesheet can be linked to diffent other stylesheets via includes if the linked-to stylesheets define a template with the same name that is called in the linking stylesheet.

Every transformation now has a root stylesheet. That will include a stylesheet which contains shared templates and a stylesheet that will contain the template that is special to the transformation.

So this would look like:

`transformation1-root.xsl`:

```
<xsl:include href="transformation-shared.xsl" />
<xsl:include href="transformation1-specific.xsl" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="templateFooBarRoot" />
</xsl:template>
```

`transformation2-root.xsl`:

```
<xsl:include href="transformation-shared.xsl" />
<xsl:include href="transformation2-specific.xsl" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="templateFooBarRoot" />
</xsl:template>
```

`transformation-shared.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template name="templateFooBarRoot">
  <!-- output some header information -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Foo" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Bar" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Bar">
  <!-- here is also some stuff -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Foo" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Foo" >
  <xsl:call-template name="transformationSpecificTemplate" />
</xsl:template>
```

`transformation1-specific.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template name="transformationSpecificTemplate">
<!-- stuff specific to transformation 1 -->
</xsl:template>
```

`transformation2-specific.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template name="transformationSpecificTemplate">
<!-- stuff specific to transformation 2 -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes. Of course you could merge transformation1-specific.xsl into transformation1-root.xsl if you wanted. You've got the key point, however.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is one very generic way of passing a strategy (similar in effect to higher-order functions in functional programming languages and in XSLT 3.0)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:t1="my:t1" xmlns:t2="my:t2" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pStrategy" select="'t1:'"/>

 <t1:strategy/>
 <t2:strategy/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStrategy" select="document('')/*/*[starts-with(name(), $pStrategy)]"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="t1:strategy">
   <xsl:param name="pNum"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="2*$pNum"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="t2:strategy">
   <xsl:param name="pNum"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pNum*$pNum"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num/text()">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vStrategy">
     <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="."/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**Strategy "t1" is executed and the result contains each original number doubled**:

```
<nums>
   <num>2</num>
   <num>4</num>
   <num>6</num>
   <num>8</num>
   <num>10</num>
   <num>12</num>
   <num>14</num>
   <num>16</num>
   <num>18</num>
   <num>20</num>
</nums>
```

**When the invoker of the transformation supplies for the global parameter $pStrategy the value 't2:', then strategy "t2" is executed and the result contains each original number squared**:

```
<nums>
   <num>1</num>
   <num>4</num>
   <num>9</num>
   <num>16</num>
   <num>25</num>
   <num>36</num>
   <num>49</num>
   <num>64</num>
   <num>81</num>
   <num>100</num>
</nums>
```

**One can read more about this powerful technique, which is the base for [the FXSL library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/) for functional programming in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 [here](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html) and [here](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/)**.

Comment: That looks really cool. However it seems that this is an advanced usage of xslt and we haven't got any xslt experts in our team. So for us it will be better to just stick with includes as we were already using these.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, There is nothing advanced in FXSL for anyone who has experience using any functional programming language. Also, using FXSL makes possible to produce very simple and short solutions to problems that otherwise seem "almost impossible to do with XSLT".